# get order of child selected jquery

Tags: jquery, children

I want to make different background color for ul children depending on their orders, how can I get the order of children using jquery.

```
<ul>
<li>a</li>
    <li>b</li>   
     <li>c</li>
     <li>d</li>
     <li>e</li>
    <li>f</li>
 </ul>

$('ul li').bind('mouseover', function(e){

    //how can I get the order of the childre
    //when hover on c it shoul returns 3
    alert("child order ");
});
```

here's an example
http://jsfiddle.net/sHefJ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that subset of HTML, using...

```
$(this).index() + 1
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WDRF6/).

...would be sufficient.

I added `1` because your numbering system in your example doesn't appear to be `0` based.

Answer (score 2):

The following will give you an index. So c would be 2, NOT 3!

```
$(this).index();
```